# Querystring comes up null in webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, query-string, response.redirect

I am running into this issue when trying to pass data between webforms. I have the querystring setup correctly and yet when trying to get the information on the second webform it comes up null.

This is my first webform where I send the data with a button click.

```
protected void btnSendData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/DataTransfer2.aspx?UserName=" + TextBoxName.Text + 
        "&UserEmail=" + TextBoxEmail.Text);
}
```

And the second webform that is to retrieve the data and present it to the user.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    LabelDynamicName.Text = Request.QueryString["UserName"];
    LabelDynamicEmail.Text = Request.QueryString["UserEmail"];                     
}
```

Comment: I can't replicate the problem

Comment: Does this same code work fine for you?

Comment: Yes same code works for me

Comment: I found the issue I had set the button's PostBackUrl from when I was using the button for testing which was causing me to lose the data when I redirected to the other webform. I have solved the issue. Thank you for the input.

Comment: glad it works   :)

Comment: The code is wrong. Please wrap Text property with Server or HttpUtility UrlEncode.